# Routing confusion in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm experiencing routing confusion in laravel 4.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'myProfile', 'before' =>   'auth|inGroup:Model|isMe'], function()
{
    Route::get('/{username}', function(){
    echo 'hello';
});
     });



 Route::get('/{username}', [
'as'        =>      'show-profile',
'uses'      =>      'ProfileController@index'
 ]);
```

When i write to address bar domain.app/myProfile it runs second route and runs ProfileController@index...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like correct behaviour. To access first route you would have to type something like `domain.app/myProfile/FooUser`. You didn't specify `/` route in myProfile route group, so it cannot match it and uses second one.

Comment: The second one also requires a parameter. So it shouldn't work as well? Edit: Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your routes:

**1)**

```
 Route::get('/{username}', [
    'as'        =>      'show-profile',
    'uses'      =>      'ProfileController@index'
 ]);
```

Use `/example` URI to access the above route.

**2)**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'myProfile', 'before' =>'auth|inGroup:Model|isMe'], function()
{
        Route::get('/{username}', function(){
        echo 'hello';
    });
 });
```

Use `/myProfile/example` URI to access the above route.

Your application is working as expected.

Comment: thanks for answer i have to accept first answer because it was first. but yours true too.